# Jenkins - watching for changes on a finer level than the stream

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, rational-team-concert

I've got a particular use case for SCM and Jenkins CI/CD server. Currently my setup only allows me to check for changes in an entire code stream. The stream itself consists of multiple Eclipse plugins.

Now, I only want to kick off my pipeline if there are changes delivered to a subset of those plugins, not the stream itself. Is there currently an effective way to achieve this?

My current idea is along the lines of parsing the changelog.xml, but I'm not exactly sure how or when this gets created. My SCM is RTC but unfortunately I cannot modify anything on that side.

Answer (score 0):

We're using something similar. We're running our deployment only in case of particular changes. You can quite easily do it using RTC Plain API (creating a script or a custom ant task) and running it as a pre-build step in jenkins.